# .htaccess to return one page for any URL?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, website

I would like to put up a "Site under maintenance" page, so that every URL request is shown this page.

What is the correct way to write a .htaccess file to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule .* under_construction.html [L]
```

This will make any URL show the under_construction.html file.  It does not use redirection, all pages have their content ignored.